# xsl:fo how to include dynamically generated svg

Tags: svg, apache-fop

I want to generate a svg chart and insert it into pdf using apache fop. So far I have tried using

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <xsl:value-of select="svgData"/>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

in xsl file and generated svg is held as a string in the "svgData". This approach is not working as it is not parsing the string svg data and just appending it.

How do I achieve this ? I need to create the svg in java (baitk?) and add it to the pdf.

Comment: Can you provide svgData content example for testing purpose?

Comment: I have the exact same question.  Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time too having headache on this problem. Finally I could make it work by using a `<xsl:copy-of>` instead of `<xsl:value-of>` + using prefixed namespace.

```
<fo:block>
  <fo:instream-foreign-object content-type="content-type:xml/svg"
                              xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/path/to/svg:svg"/>
  </fo:instream-foreign-object>
</fo:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent many hours solving the problem. Without success. My recommendation is not to pursue this approach any further.

My solution to get dynamic SVG into a PDF is the following.
Save the SVG on your hard disk and remember the filename/path in the object.
Then use the filename to fill the external-graphic src attribute.
After creating the PDF the svg-files have to be deleted.

Done.

XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="qandapair">
   <fo:block text-align="center">
       <fo:external-graphic src="{chart}"/>
   </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

XML:

```
     <qandapair>
         <chart>gaoejTLVfcBUrCgjvmsWgjBwQzHYmYYJ.svg</chart>
     ...
     </qandapair>
```